# hover Selector not workin on image Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

sorry for my English..I'm very new with javascript...

I have two javascript Code;

One for image gallery with **ekko-lightbox**,

```
$(document).on("click", '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {

     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).ekkoLightbox({alwaysShowClose: true});
});
```

and one more for Zoom but also working as hover for small image gallery,

```
var zoomConfig = {cursor: 'crosshair', zoomType: "inner" }; 
var image = $('#gallery_01 a');
var zoomImage = $('img#zoom_03');

zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom

image.hover(function(){
 // Remove old instance od EZ
$('.zoomContainer').remove();
 zoomImage.removeData('elevateZoom');
 // Update source for images
 zoomImage.attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
 zoomImage.data('zoom-image', $(this).data('zoom-image'));
  // Reinitialize EZ
  zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);
});
```

Hier all my code javascript, Html and Css,

```js
var zoomConfig = {cursor: 'crosshair', zoomType: "inner" }; 
var image = $('#gallery_01 a');
var zoomImage = $('img#zoom_03');

zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom

image.on('click', function(){
   // Remove old instance od EZ
   $('.zoomContainer').remove();
  zoomImage.removeData('elevateZoom');
  // Update source for images
  zoomImage.attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
  zoomImage.data('zoom-image', $(this).data('zoom-image'));
  // Reinitialize EZ
  zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);
});

$(document).on("click", '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).ekkoLightbox({alwaysShowClose: true});
});
```

```css
  
.grosse-bild { position: relative; margin-left: 0;width: 52%; display: block; box-sizing: border-box;   background-color: black;  

 }

 .grosse-bild > img { position:relative; max-height:100%;     max-width: 100; vertical-align: middle; border: 0;
 }
 #lalo {width: 5%; margin-right: 10px; margin-right: 7px;}
 #gallery_01{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: '';
  margin-top: 1%;
 }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elevatezoom/3.0.8/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js"></script>


 <div class="container">
   <div class="grosse-bild">
    
     <img style="border:1px solid #e8e8e6;" id="zoom_03" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg" width="100%"  />
    </div>
    <div id="gallery_01">
 
       <a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-update="" data-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" >
       </a>
       <a href="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg"  data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"  "> 
       <img src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg"  width="100" class="img-fluid thumb" />
       </a>
       <a  href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" >
       </a>
       <a href="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg"  data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"  > 
       <img src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" width="100"  class="img-fluid thumb" />
       </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

so, my problem, the **hover** of the small image gallery not working, the rest of the code working.

I'll the small gallery Two things, with hover display on the big window, now does it, and when clicking it open an image gallery

Can someone explain to me with easy words how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed again code ;)

```js
var zoomConfig = {cursor: 'crosshair', zoomType: "inner" }; 
var image = $('#gallery_01 a');
var zoomImage = $('img#zoom_03');

zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);//initialise zoom

image.hover(function(){
   // Remove old instance od EZ
   $('.zoomContainer').remove();
  zoomImage.removeData('elevateZoom');
  // Update source for images
  zoomImage.attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
  zoomImage.data('zoom-image', $(this).data('zoom-image'));
  // Reinitialize EZ
  zoomImage.elevateZoom(zoomConfig);
});

$(document).on("click", '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).ekkoLightbox({alwaysShowClose: true});
});
```

```css
.grosse-bild { position: relative; margin-left: 0;width: 52%; display: block; box-sizing: border-box;   background-color: black;  

 }

 .grosse-bild > img { position:relative; max-height:100%;     max-width: 100; vertical-align: middle; border: 0;
 }
 #lalo {width: 5%; margin-right: 10px; margin-right: 7px;}
 #gallery_01{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: '';
  margin-top: 1%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.2.0/ekko-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elevatezoom/3.0.8/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
   <div class="grosse-bild">
    
     <img style="border:1px solid #e8e8e6;" id="zoom_03" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg" width="100%"  />
    </div>
    <div id="gallery_01">
 
      <a  href="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-update="" data-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery">
   <img src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg" width="100"  />
    </a>

   <a  href="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update="" data-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery">
   <img src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg" width="100"  />
   </a>

   <a  href="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image3.jpg" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-update=""   data-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image3.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image3.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery">
   <img class="window" src="https://raw.github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image3.jpg" width="100"  />
   </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You wrong some part of html code.

Comment: Gracie for your answer!, but now the problem i not to come the image gallery...I'll to come as here https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/Lot9pk3q/9/

Comment: yes, but also to want when to click the small image, open an image gallery as here https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/Lot9pk3q/9/ , I'll the small gallery Two things, with **hover** display on the big window, now does it, and when clicking it open an image gallery...

Comment: On my First question when clicking the smaller image open a window image gallery, but not working the **hover**, with your code, working the **hover** but not open the window image gallery....

Comment: Yes! , molllllto Gracie!,  io ti aguro una Bella giornata!